# Multiple Imputation: How to only impute certain predictor & auxiliary variables

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multiple-imputation, mice

I've imputed variables to conduct a multiple regression analysis in SPSS but unfortunately SPSS doesn't provide certain pooled values, like R², standardized betas, etc. It looks like I have to conduct my analyses in **R**. I've looked into the MI procedure using `mice()` and so far I have understood most steps. However, every example I've found just uses `mice()` without specifying predictor and auxiliary variables. Since I'm only working with a subset of data off a bigger dataset, I would like to specify which variables to impute. How can I do that? If you have an exemplary **R** command, I would greatly appreciate that, since I'm new to using this software.

Comment: I can't check it now, but I doubt that SPSS `doesn't provide certain pooled values`. I expect it should. Are you using the MI regime correctly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using it correctly. Unfortunately, as for now, SPSS just doesn't seem to provide certain pooled values (as can be seen here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/pooled-results-not-produced-r-square-and-see-values-multiple-imputation).

Comment: Is it maybe possible to reduce my variables to just the ones I need to impute (delete the others) and compute the main analysis with only the few variables I need?

Comment: What I might recommend is to ask personally David Nichols https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/265536/david-nichols who was a principal statistician in SPSS Inc.